How could I merge the dataset and save it as CSV after splitting it to X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test?
How could I merge the dataset and save it as CSV after splitting it to
X = df.drop(['label'],axis=1).values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values.reshape(-1,1)
y=np.ravel(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, train_size = 0.8, 
test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0,stratify = y)

I want to merge the dataset back and save it as a CSV file, but without changing in the features names or orders or anything?

This should help you? Pandas Merging 101

What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please [edit] and add the tag for it.

And what's train_test_split? Is that from sklearn? You might want to add the tag for that too, and definitely a topic tag like [tag:train-test-split] or [tag:machine-learning].

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips. (Adding relevant tags is one of them :)

np.concatenate or pd.concat can help here for example like this (but without saving an initial rows order):
train_full = np.hstack((X_train, y_train.reshape(-1, 1)))
test_full = np.hstack((X_test, y_test.reshape(-1, 1)))

df_full = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((train_full, test_full), axis = 0), columns = df.columns)
df_full.to_csv('data.csv')

